# How to merge two files by line names using python

Tags: python, file, merge

I think this should be easy but yet have not been able to solve it. I have two files as below and I want to merge them in a way that lines starting with `>` in the file1 to be the header of the lines in the file2

file1:

```
>seq12
ACGCTCGCA
>seq34
GCATCGCGT
>seq56
GCGATGCGC
```

file2:

```
ATCGCGCATGATCTCAG
AGCGCGCATGCGCATCG
AGCAAATTTAGCAACTC
```

so the desired output should be:

```
>seq12
ATCGCGCATGATCTCAG
>seq34
AGCGCGCATGCGCATCG
>seq56
AGCAAATTTAGCAACTC
```

I have tried this code so far but in output, all the lines coming from file2 are the same:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

with open(file1) as fw:
    with open(file2,'r') as rv:
        for line in rv:
            items = line
        for record in SeqIO.parse(fw, 'fasta'):
            print('>' + record.id)
            print(line)
```

Comment: If the files are small enough to read in as lists you could preprocess file 1  and use the zip function.
https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-zip-two-lists-in-python

Comment: You intend to ignore the even lines at `file1`? On another note, what have you tried so far? And what were the results, what is not working? It is nice to show some code snippets of what you tried and the problems you found.

Comment: Unfortunately my file are big - around 9000 lines

Comment: I just updated the question and put the cod I tried

Comment: Unless the lines are really long I think that 9000 should fit in memory easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot store your files in memory, you need a solution that reads line by line from each file, and writes accordingly to the output file. The following program does that. The comments try to clarify, though I believe it is clear from the code.

```py
with open("file1.txt") as first, open("file2.txt") as second, open("output.txt", "w+") as output:
    while 1:
        line_first = first.readline()       # line from file1 (header)
        line_second = second.readline()     # line from file2 (body)
        if not (line_first and line_second):
            # if any file has ended
            break

        # write to output file
        output.writelines([line_first, line_second])
        # jump one line from file1
        first.readline()
```

Note that this will only work if `file1.txt` has the specific format you presented (odd lines are headers, even lines are useless).
In order to allow a bit more customization, you can wrap it up in a function as:

```py
def merge_files(header_file_path, body_file_path, output_file="output.txt", every_n_lines=2):
    with open(header_file_path) as first, open(body_file_path) as second, open(output_file, "w+") as output:
        while 1:
            line_first = first.readline()       # line from header
            line_second = second.readline()     # line from body
            if not (line_first and line_second):
                # if any file has ended
                break

            # write to output file
            output.writelines([line_first, line_second])
            # jump n lines from header
            for _ in range(every_n_lines - 1):
                first.readline()
```

And then calling `merge_files("file1.txt", "file2.txt")` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If both files are small enough to fit in memory simultaneously, you can simply read them simultaneously and interleave them.

```
# Open two file handles.
with open("f1", mode="r") as f1, open("f2", mode="r") as f2:
    lines_first = f1.readlines()   # Read all lines in f1.  
    lines_second = f2.readlines()  # Read all lines in f2. 


lines_out = []

# For each line in the file without headers...
for idx in range(len(lines_second)):
    # Take every even line from the first file and prepend it to 
    # the line from the second.
    lines_out.append(lines_first[2 * idx + 1].rstrip() + lines_second[idx].rstrip())
```

You can generate the `seq` headers *very* easily given `idx`: I leave this as an exercise to the reader.

If either or both files are too large to fit in memory, you can repeat the above process line-by-line over both handles (using one variable to store information from the file with headers).